# What exactly package "gobjc" installs?

Tags: linux, debian, objective-c

Trying to figure out what exactly "gobjc" installs, I did:

`sudo dpkg -L gobjc` and got a path to `/usr/share/doc/gobjc`

Did : `sudo apt-file list gobjc` and got a path to `/usr/share/doc/gobjc`

on this directory you can only find text files that are .gz compress, I was expecting to find some .a, .o or any kind of file that actually process code as this package is used to compile objective-c code

Comment: debian and cygwin use completely difference package systems. Using both tags is a bad idea

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `apt show gobjc`:

```
Depends: cpp (>= 4:8.3.0-1), gcc (>= 4:8.3.0-1), gobjc-8 (>= 8.3.0-1~)
Description:
 This is a dependency package providing the default GNU Objective-C compiler.
```

The actual compiler gets installed through the `gobjc-8` package:

```
$ apt-file list gobjc-8
gobjc-8: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1obj
```

It is not a standalone tool – only a backend that will be automatically used by the `gcc` frontend whenever you try to compile an Obj-C source file.